# Liberator: Setting :representation :media-type in :media-type-available?

Tags: clojure, liberator

I wanted to use a decision point `:media-type-available?` but I failed...

I know I have to set the `:representation :media-type` but I don't really know how to do it.

So far, my code looks as the following:

```
(defresource test-resource []
  :media-type-available (fn [req]
    (assoc req :representation {:media-type "application/json"}))
  :available-media-types ["application/json" "text/html"]
  :handle-ok (fn [req] {:ok true})
)
```

Remarks:

1. `(assoc req :representation {:media-type "application/json"})` produces a correct map with "changed" `req` object.
2. in `:handle-ok`'s `req` object, the `:representation` value is `{}`

I have no idea how to set it (it's not a mutable object, is it?) and looking at the liberator's source code doesn't really help...

Thanks,
Karol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK... It was just a typo... Instead of `:representation` I had `:represenation`...

So if anybody interested, there are two ways of solving this:

1. return `req` object with merged `:representation`:

   ```
   :media-type-available (fn [req]
     (assoc req :representation {:media-type "application/json"}))
   ```
2. return only the `:representation` object:

   ```
   :media-type-available (fn [req]
     {:representation {:media-type "application/json"}})
   ```